# Use database partition information to partition spring batch job

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-batch, partitioning

I have 60 database tables each containing 1 billion records. I am planning to run one batch job per table, and would like to use local partitioning to speed things up. These tables are partitioned based on a date column in the database.

I would like to configure the batch job partitioning based solely on the information I obtain from ***information_schema.partitions*** table. I couldn't find any stuff that uses database partition information. I went through lot of spring batch tutorials,  I only saw some min and max values being set based on some column. Can somebody please advice?

Comment: please share your schema

Comment: Decided not use the partitions at all. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch does not provide a `Partitioner` implementation that does that for you out of the box.  That being said, you can implement your own `Partitioner` that will do this functionality.  You can read more about the `Partitioner` interface in the javadoc here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/Partitioner.html